# Error when installing 'pycryptodome'

Tags: python, macos, pip

Whenever I install the package, I get this string out:-

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/l8/nrwgdgr96v33vfcd95r2yl3m0000gp/T/pip-build-AJpKPV/pycryptodomex/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/l8/nrwgdgr96v33vfcd95r2yl3m0000gp/T/pip-GEiSB1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l8/nrwgdgr96v33vfcd95r2yl3m0000gp/T/pip-build-AJpKPV/pycryptodomex/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to upgrade `pip` first?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And then install the `pycryptodome` package.